# Why "try...else" is "invalid syntax" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

normal:

```
try:
    something may go wrong...
except:
    pass
else:
    others func...
```

what i need:

```
try:
    something may go wrong...
else:
    others func...
```

Are there some reasons for 'try...else' not exists?

Comment: What should supposedly happen in your `try...else` example? do you mean `try...finally`?

Comment: @DeepSpace When any wrong not happened, I want to execute the else block. But try...finally will always be executed.

Comment: What's wrong with `except: pass`? It's just 12 characters, no harm in typing it. :P It also makes the code more readable (e.g. "Here, I will pass the exception...").

Comment: And what should happen when something wrong **does** happen? The Python motto says "explicit is better than implicit". If you want to ignore an exception you must explicitly say so.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS hh, ok, i got it. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was supported, the syntax

```
try:
    something may go wrong...
else:
    others func...
```

would be exactly equivalent in behaviour to

```
something may go wrong...
others func...
```

i.e. you do not need any special syntax for it

Comment: but if "something may go wrong..." went wrong, i just want to ignore it instead of raise it.

Comment: @Tr0y So ignore it with `except: pass` just like you are doing in the first example. This is how exceptions are ignored in Python

Comment: @Tr0y then the syntax is wrong. To catch the thrown exception you need to have an `except`, not an `else`. an `else` block serves only to execute code after the try block ended without an exception thrown...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, i got it! :D